# No module named MySQLdb when trying to load the OpenStack dashboard

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to install OpenStack Dashboard following this guide from git: http://wiki.openstack.org/OpenStackDashboard

But when I run this command to sync database:

```
$ tools/with_venv.sh openstack-dashboard/manage.py syncdb
```

It returns that:

```
File "/home/user1/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/db/backends/mysql>    /base.py", line 14, in <module>    
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I installed package "**python-mysqldb**" several times, but it's still raised this error.
When I run:

**>>> import MySQLdb**

in python interpreter, it's fine!

And I tried to install through easy_install, but the MySQL-python is installed:

```
$ sudo easy_install MySQL-python
```

> Searching for MySQL-python
>
> Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3
>   MySQL-python 1.2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Using /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
>
> Processing dependencies for MySQL-python
>
> Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python

Here are the content of tools/with_venv.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
TOOLS=`dirname $0`
VENV=$TOOLS/../.venv
source $VENV/bin/activate && $@
```

When I run: **tools/with_venv.sh** it returns nothing.

What's wrong in my case?

Comment: Seems like your `virtualenv` was run with `--no-site-packages` try running it without this arguments OR install mysqldb from within the virtualenv. i.e. `easy_install MySQL-python`

Comment: could you paste the content of `tools/with_venv.sh` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in launchpad too. Thank God they help me solve this problem. 
https://answers.launchpad.net/horizon/+question/189051

By running this command to install MySQL-python

```
$ tools/with_venv.sh pip install MySQL-python
```

@ Ken: Thank you. You're right. But I don't understand what's the difference between **easy_install** and **pip** command! I will check it later.

Answer (score 3):

With virtualenv, you have your own environment specifically for that application. If you use `--no-site-packages`, it won't use system modules installed beyond the standard library.

The solution is to activate the virtual environment and install them there. Try something like this:

```
cd (project directory)
source bin/activate
easy_install MySQL-python
```

In doing so, you will install MySQLdb inside that project's own virtual environment, and it will be separate from the system-wide installation. The advantage of virtualenv is that it lets you keep multiple versions of software contained exactly where you need them.

Comment: Yes I done all those commands but you can see in my post. It announces that MySQL-python is active, but it is in the system-wide installation. I understand what you means but I can not install MySQL-python in the virtual environment.

Comment: When you run the source bin/activate script, does it change your prompt to say (project name) before it?

Comment: In my case I run '$ source .venv/bin/activate' but it only return s '(.venv)' then nothing happen.

Comment: My guess is something is wrong with the virtual environment itself. Or maybe you're using an unusual shell?